# NPM conflicts with dependencies when installed locally using file path

Tags: node.js, npm

I am developing two npm packages, say `@ffx/alpha` and `@ffx/beta`. Beta package is dependant on Alpha package.

```
alpha/package.json

{
   "name": "@ffx/alpha",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "dependencies": {},
   "devDependencies": {
      "some-package": "1.0.0"
   }
}
```

```
beta/package.json

{
   "name": "@ffx/alpha",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "peerDependencies": {
      "@ffx/alpha": "^1.0.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "some-package": "1.0.0"
   }
}
```

For local testing, I am building the Alpha project and install built code using following command inside the Beta project root,

`npm install ../alpha/dist/@ffx/alpha`

Also, I start building Alpha project in watch mode so that code changes in Alpha project reflect in Beta project (inside node_modules) immediately.

My issue is that, in some scenarios where I use the same dependancy in both Alpha and Beta project (`some-package` in above setup) Beta project get wrong reference of the same package and throw an error.

Example:
Say Alpha project has following code,

```
...
let smpkg = new SomePackage();
...
```

In Beta project, it will throw an error saying types missmatch.

**error TS2322: Type 'import("~/alpha/node_modules/some-package").SomePackage' is not assignable to type 'import("~/beta/node_modules/some-package").SomePackage'.**

Is there a way to align both references using this method?

Or is there a alternative way to use packages locally before publishing?

NOTE: I've already tried `npm link` and `npm pack` with mixed results.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.  This is how I managed to fix (I'll use your alpha/beta terminology):

1. Delete node_modules folders from both alpha and beta
2. Ensure any matching libraries in the package.json files for both alpha and beta match exactly.  (For example, some-package should use 1.x.x instead ^1.x.x)
3. Run npm install on alpha
4. Ensure package.json for beta is pointed to local module (For example, @ffx/alpha: file:../alpha/dist/@ffx/alpha)
5. Run npm install on beta

This ended fixing everything for me.